# ffmpeg output 2 different audio files each to a different output device at the same time

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Does anyone know if it is possible to use FFMPEG to output 2 audio files each to a different output device (i.e. sound card) using one command?

If so, how?
If not possible with FFMPEG is there any other free tool that allows this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path of the folder when you define outputs.

Tested on Windows: `ffmpeg -i "input.mp3" D:\output1.mp3 C:\output2.mp3`

Source: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

Comment: my post is not 100% clear sorry... what I need is to be able to output to two different audio devices not to two different files. imagine you want to output one sound to your laptop's sound card and another sound to an usb sound card connected to your laptop with one FFMPEG command i.e. at the same time. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For two inputs, to different outputs, it's

```
ffmpeg -i A.mp3 -i B.mp3 -map 0 Aout.mp3 -map 1 Bout.mp3
```

Comment: my post is not 100% clear sorry... what I need is to be able to output to two different audio devices not to two different files. thanks!

Comment: Which devices ?

Comment: sound cards. imagine you want to output one sound to your laptop's sound card and another sound to an usb sound card connected to your laptop with one FFMPEG command i.e. at the same time